# Jquery drag box to mouse click location

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a div that is draggable using Jquery UI. Right now you can click and drag the div back and forth inside of the parent, the problem is that I need to also be able to click somewhere in the parent and have the div automatically get dragged to that location and start the drag event if the user decides to continue moving the mouse from that location. I was just wondering if this is possible.

Here is a JSFiddle of what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/ky2xLskx/

```
$( "#handle" ).draggable({ containment:"parent" });
```

To put it as simply as possible, the red box needs to act like the scrollbar of a page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible that you want to achieve. you can check the click event on parent container and the animate the box to that specific location.

```
$( "#handle" ).parent().click(function(e){

    var w = $( "#handle" ).width();
    var w2 = w/2;
    var mx = e.clientX;
    var my = e.clientY;
    var dx = $(this).offset().left;
    var lx = $(this).width()+dx;
    var posX=mx-dx-w2;
    if((mx-dx)<w){
         posX = 0;
    }
    if((lx-mx)<w){
         posX =$(this).width()-w;
    }
    $( "#handle" ).animate({left:posX+'px'},500);
});
```

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky2xLskx/3/)